# How can I get the bitcoin amount of an bitcoin address which doesn't belong to my wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-cli

I am trying to make a query about a bitcoin address's btc amount. As I've [read](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/57065/why-bitcoin-cli-getreceivedbyaddress-always-returns-0), **getreceivedbyaddress** rpc command can only be used for the addresses of a wallet that one owns and that command is awallet command. I want to make a query about any bitcoin addresses btc amount. Is it possible? If yes, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new `scantxoutset` method to check for UTXOs matching a given script, address, or key descriptor.

For example, to scan an address, you can use:

```
bitcoin-cli scantxoutset start "[\"addr(1....)\"]"
```

Comment: Does it scan all the txs in the bitcoin db to find that specific tx which that specific adress is in the utxo set of that tx?

Comment: It only scans the txs in the utxo set - any outputs that have already been spent will not be considered

Comment: When I run that comment, it takes 1-2 min but when I do the query on blockchain.info, it happens in seconds. Why? Can it be that they downloaded the bitcoin database and tweaked it so it computes very fast? I am asking because I need fast results too if possible. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @EfeCini Explorers extract all this information into a separate database optimized for their query patterns. You will not be able to match that speed using just Bitcoin Core, and should consider running a service such as Insight or ElectrumX on top of it